# findstr with regex command doesnt work in C# and Batch but works fine in CMD

Tags: c#, regex, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I'm trying to use findstr command from C# with a regex parameter but it doesn´t work, despite the same command works great in cmd.

**CMD commad:**

```
findstr /r /c:".*Gomez.*" "C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\*"
```

`Gomez` can be replaced by another word or a number, without spaces or any other special character.

Example of a .txt file content where I want to search:

```
Name: Albert Surname: Einstein Phone: XXXX Address: XXXX       
Name: John Surname: Cobra Phone: XXXX Address: XXXX   
Name: Jennifer Surname: Gomez Phone: XXXX Address: XXXX   
Name: Tim Surname: Cornwell Phone: XXXX Address: XXXX
```

I want to search by surname, so my findstr command in CMD will be: `findstr /r /c:".*Gomez.*" "C:\Users\USER_NAME\FOLDER\*.txt"`
If I try to implement the regex `".*Gomez.*"` in C# or Batch it doesn't work

**C# code:**

If I use a string as a parameter for findstr it works, but at the moment I use any kind of regex expression (have read the docs and know it only supports regex partially) it either doesn´t do anything or hangs VS.

```
string regexCommand = "/C findstr .*Gomez.* \"C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\Desktop\\*\"";
string stringCommand = "/C findstr \"Gomez\" \"C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\Desktop\\*\"";

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = regexCommand;

p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
```

---

Have also tried the same approach using Batch with the same result, using a string works but with regex it doesn´t do anything. Is that a bug in the findstr tool?

**Batch script:**

```
@echo off
set regexCommand=findstr .*Gomez.* "C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\*"
set stringCommand=findstr "Gomez" "C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\*"

%regexCommand%
%stringCommand%

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('%regexCommand%') do (set output=%%i)
echo %output%
```

Comment: @Charlieface - `/r Processes search strings as regular expressions. This is the default setting.` literally from the link you posted. It's a subset of BRE that can't handle quantifiers, but it's still regex.

Comment: However `.*TEXT.*` which should really have been `".*TEXT.*"`, means any character zero or more times, followed by the case sensitive string `TEXT`, followed by any character zero or more times. That would essentially be the same as `TEXT`, and that means there's no need for a regular expression, or findstr in fact. How about you explain to us with a real world example, what your actual search is supposed to match, against an example list. That way we'd be able to provide more focused assistance. I find it odd to use cmd.exe and findstr.exe from a proper programming language to get this done!

Comment: @Compo I just use TEXT as a name, code, or number. For example, think about a phone number that I want to find in a bunch of files. I want to use findstr because its really fast, more than opening hundreds of files, loading all the lines and looping through them until I match the number that I want. The problem is that I dont know why if I run the command in the cmd it works great and in C# and Batch it doesnt (using regex in the findstr command, if I use a plain string it works fine).

Comment: Provide us with a [mcve], or simply delete your question. We cannot help you with made up commands consisting of fake search strings.

Comment: @Compo I have hundreds of .txt files with client data. Example of a .txt file content: Name: Albert Surname: Einstein Phone: XXXX Address: XXXX
Name: John Surname: Cobra Phone: XXXX Address: XXXX
Name: Jennifer Surname: Gomez Phone: XXXX Address: XXXX
Name: Tim Surname: Cornwell Phone: XXXX Address: XXXX

I want to search by surname, so my findstr command in CMD will be:
findstr /r /c:".*Gomez.*" "C:\Users\USER_NAME\FOLDER\*.txt"

If I try to implement the regex ".*Gomez.*" in C# or Batch it doesnt work

Comment: Code is not going to find cmd.exe.  You need to use full path to the executable.

Comment: Please use the [edit] facility, and put all the pertinent information we need, into the question itself. Our members/future readers should not have to wade through the comments, in order to understand the full extent of your question. BTW, are your `.txt` files really `.vcf`? Also, as I've already mentioned `findstr /r /c:".*Gomez.*" "C:\Users\USER_NAME\FOLDER*.txt"` is the same as `findstr "Gomez" "C:\Users\USER_NAME\FOLDER*.txt"` or `findstr /l "Gomez" "C:\Users\USER_NAME\FOLDER*.txt"`. No regular expression is needed. Maybe `/r "\<Gomez\>"`, would be better!

Comment: Please note that you've specifically stated, `TEXT` can be a single word or a number, without spaces or any other special character.. That means other than the `\<TEXT\>` _(word)_, example, you would not need any other type of findstr regular expression. You are simply matching a series of standard non special characters.

Comment: @Compo Have updated the question, thanks for the tip. Yes, I know that in my case I can just use the literal string search, but I want to know why the regex is not working if they apparently are the same, and it works via CMD but not if I run it from C#

Comment: So your question, or the answer you want, has to fix for you the wrong search string for your task. You most certainly, for the task you've explained should be using, ```%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "\<TEXT\>" "%UserProfile%\FOLDER\*.txt"```. And as an argument to `var\cmd.exe`,  ```/D /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "\<TEXT\>" "%UserProfile%\FOLDER\*.txt""```, where `var` is the result of ```Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));```. Then all you need to do is escape the characters as necessary!

Comment: findstr.exe is an executable; it is not part of cmd.exe.  Why not call it directly instead of going thorough the pain of cmd.exe

Comment: Your search expression is not very reliable; imagine there is a line `Name: Brent Surname: Fitz …` and another one `Name: Fitzpatrick Surname: Moore …`; the command line `findstr ".*Fitz.*"` would return both of them; however, `findstr "\<Fitz\>" …`, or even better, `findstr /R /C:"\<Surname: Fitz\>" …`, just returns the second one…

Comment: @cup that´s a good point, thanks man!

Comment: @aschipfl The main problem was the inconsistency between running findstr with a Regex expression directly from the cmd and from C#. Deleting the bin folder (so VS does a "new" build) has fixed the problem. Don't really know why but from time to time it happens and it does the trick.